# Tracing a Doxygen documentation page back to the source repo

Tags: git, repository, doxygen

Here's the problem: I need to create a Doxygen project that includes only the pages in one "chapter" of an existing project. To do that I need to know which of the existing project's source files generate those pages, and then which repo(s) the files are in.

(Here I'm using "source file" to mean a file that the Doxygen project reads; not a file containing source code.)

Going from files to repos should be easy because the config file's "input" setting gives each file's pathname, which I can connect to a repo pathname. How do I go from documentation pages to source files?

I thought that the description of each element on a page would tell me the name of the source file it's declared in, but most of the element descriptions don't identify a source file. I think variable and structure declarations do, but functions don't.